# BeautifulSoup returns None

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

i am trying to get the title of the listing in [this URL](https://www.lamudi.com.ph/metro-manila/makati/condominium/buy/), but this code returns None.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

# get the data 
data = requests.get('https://www.lamudi.com.ph/metro-manila/makati/condominium/buy/')

# Update Header
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
})
# load data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

# We need to extract all the data in this div: <div 
class="ListingCell-KeyInfo-title" ..>

listingsTitle = soup.find('div', { 'class': 'ListingCell-KeyInfo-title'})
print(listingsTitle)
```

Any idea why is that?

Thanks

Comment: In the soup that is created , there is no div with class 'ListingCell-KeyInfo-title' and as @Bob says in his answer below because the site is treating you as bot it may have removed some information

Comment: scraping this website is harder than what you thought

Comment: It appears so :(

Answer (score 0):

**The url you request treat you as a bot.**

Request response:

```
h1>Pardon Our Interruption...</h1>
<p>
      As you were browsing <strong>www.lamudi.com.ph</strong> something about your 
browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:
        </p>
<ul>
```

Before you parse anything from the response.

Print the content first to make sure you have access the url in right way.

You have to add User-Agent or somthing else to make you like a **real user**

Try add this into your request headers :

```
USER_AGENT_FIREFOX= 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'
```

Comment: I added this but same thing. 
`# Update Header
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
})`

Answer (score 0):

I tried with selenium and with specific wait but do not works.
If you print the soup you can get the error. In fact the page return this: **"As you were browsing **www.lamudi.com.ph** something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:... "**

The website recognise that you are not human.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

# get the data 
data = requests.get('https://www.lamudi.com.ph/metro-manila/makati/condominium/buy/')

# load data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

# We need to extract all the data in this div: <div class="ListingCell-KeyInfo-title" ..>
print(soup)    #--> this print get the error

listingsTitle = soup.find('div', class_='ListingCell-KeyInfo-title')
print(listingsTitle)
```